# Access attributes on featureCollection

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, fields-attributes, features, json

The geoJSON-String:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {"title": "Standort 1 "},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.444175720214844,
          52.580522509085554
        ]
      }
    }
    ,...
  ]
}
```

This is my code to read and create the features to markers in openlayers:

```
var geo = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();

var obj = JSON.parse(featureJson);
var features = geo.read(obj, "FeatureCollection");

alert(features[0].attributes.length);
```

This works fine and I'm able to create the markers.

But what am I missing on this line?

```
for(var i=0;i < features.length;i++) {
    alert(features[i].attributes.title);
}
```

The output = "undefined".

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have

```
for(var i=0;i < features.length;i++) {
alert(features[i].attributes.title);
}
```

Not

```
for(var i=0;i < features.length;i++) {
alert(attributes[i].attributes.title);
}
```

Comment: You are right...sorry just an error in my post. But the code isnt working...